# Как с помощью команды вытащить комментарий у столбца в PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, bash

Имеется консольна версия субд PostgreSQL 8.4.

Как выгрузить данные в таблицу, чтобы в наименовании столбца был написан комментарий к нему, а не его имя.

Дело в том, что чаще всего там написано наименование на русском, что делает таблицу более читабельный после экспорта.

С ключами -c, -H и выводом данных > знаком. Вариант с изменением представления столбца по типу     as 'Имя столбца' не применим, тоесть нужен вариант без ковыряния ручками запроса.

Comment: А тег `mysql` зачем?

Comment: возможно, вам поможет это сообщение (https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/006301c3dea2$bf157ab0$6400a8c0@Dell4500), говорят, можно получить данные по oid: ``select description from pg_description where objoid = 306461 and
objsubid = 0;``